# Everything seems correct but I get "ValueError: time data" when parsing a timestamp

Tags: python, timestamp

It seems that the format is correct but I still get this error. What could be the problem here?

```
ValueError: time data '2016-09-16 11:36:28' does not match format '%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
```

Comment: You want `%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S` `Y` is 4-digit year `y` is 2-digit

Comment: It works this ways :). Documentation tho says otherwise: https://www.evernote.com/l/AT5UgolKVCBGDKZJsZe3jBjoSJlByRxR7oI

Comment: Sorry are you misreading the document? it states `%Y year with century as a decimal number`

Comment: https://media2.giphy.com/media/3xz2BLBOt13X9AgjEA/200w.gif

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `%Y` for 4-digit years:

```
In [10]:
d='2016-09-16 11:36:28'
dt.datetime.strptime(d, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

Out[10]:
datetime.datetime(2016, 9, 16, 11, 36, 28)
```

see the docs: https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior